# Login to VM downloaded from Google Compute Engine

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualization, vmware-fusion, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I downloaded the disk for a google compute instance as a vmdk and I'm able to bring it up in VMware Fusion (it's a debian 10 instance). However when I run it locally it's prompting me a for username & password whereas when the vm runs in the cloud it logs in automatically (I believe google cloud manages this through ssh keys). Any ideas on how to perform the authentication when running the vm locally would be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you have the SSH private key? If yes, log in using SSH. Otherwise, IIRC, you must enable password-based login and create a root password before downloading the image.

Comment: If you know Linux well, you can attach the VMDK to another VM, mount the root file system, chroot, and configure password-based login.

Comment: @JohnHanley Connect to ssh/Configure ssh are disabled on the instance in VM ware fusion. Do I need these to be enabled in order to login using SSH?
https://d.pr/i/SjrGm0

Comment: Also, password authentication was already enabled in the sshd_config file prior to downloading the image from GCE:
https://d.pr/i/4gU4dU

Comment: I do not use VMware Fusion, but I do use VMware Workstation. What do you mean by ssh is disabled in VMware Fusion? When you enabled password-based login before downloading the image, did you also create a password for the root user? That is two different steps.

Comment: Yeah, I confirmed that the user could login on google cloud before downloading the image and trying to login in the local instance. It's actually working now using the password-based login (it was weird because it wasn't working, and then at that point I hadn't changed anything, and then the next time I tried it, it worked). Thanks for your help

Comment: OK - I recommend deleting your post as your problem is probably caused by human error.